# How to text ignore line breaks in react-native

Tags: react-native, text

When the word that comes after certain signs does not fit on the line, the whole word is placed on a new line. I want to continue until the end of the line

[image]

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
<Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink' }}>                    
{"111111111111111t111111111111111111111111111111@bcbcbs.pppppppppp.com"}
     </Text>
<View>
```

I didn't add any style, it goes down again

Comment: Share your styles please.

Comment: ok, I shared @DavidScholz

Comment: The parent views as well please. It works if the text is embedded in a plain fragment with no styles.

Comment: Sorry, I added full code :)

Comment: Works on my setup

Comment: Hmmm I still have a problem